# How to troubleshoot Windows XP boot process?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, troubleshooting, debug

I have an [XP installation that won't boot properly](https://superuser.com/questions/157468/cloned-xp-wont-boot-properly-stuck-before-log-in-user-select-screen). Windows boots until just *before* I have the option to select a user. I can't get into Windows normally (and Safe Mode is the same) to check things like the Event Viewer.

**Is there a way of checking where Windows has got stuck and why?**

What tools does Windows XP already have to do this? Are there other tools or apps to highlight what is going wrong?

I realise I could just reinstall or repair XP, but I don't really want to without knowing that it can't (easily) be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

By chance, happened upon a fantastic MSDN article [How Windows Starts Up](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ntdebugging/how-windows-starts-up-part-1-of-4), [Part 2 - Bootloader Phase](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ntdebugging/how-windows-starts-up-part-the-second) *(- there should be four parts but I can't locate the other two.)*

There's even one about [How Windows Shuts Down](https://web.archive.org/web/20151203220510/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2007/06/09/how-windows-shuts-down.aspx).

Also, there's [Troubleshooting the Startup Phase](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb457123%28v=technet.10%29?redirectedfrom=MSDN).